# Mail flow rules using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices

I'm looking for a way to set [Mail flow rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/mail-flow-rules-transport-rules-0) using Microsoft Graph API, but can't find anything in the documentation on that.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

No you can only create Mailbox Rules (Inbox Rules) with either the Graph or Exchange Web Services. Mail Flow (Transport Rules) can only be created through Remote Powershell (or the admin console) which you can invoke pro-grammatically https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/ff326159(v%3Dexchg.140)